# Resolving `+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:error:]` deprecation leads to 'data couldn’t be read' error

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have this code and it works:

```
Foo *foo = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:data error:&error];
```

However, it gives me this warning:

> 'unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead

When I try to make that simple replacement with:

```
Foo *foo = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[Foo class] fromData:data error:&error];
```

... it fails with the following error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

How do I properly replace this deprecated method with a non-deprecated method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your object conforms to `NSCoding`, but it should be conforming to `NSSecureCoding`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2962884-unarchivedobjectofclass?language=objc) for unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:, you'll notice it says:

> **Important**
>   Make sure you have adopted NSSecureCoding in the types you decode. If any call to a decode-prefixed method fails, the default decodingFailurePolicy sets the error rather than throwing an exception. In this case, the current and all subsequent decode calls return 0 or nil.

Thus you'll need to do the following to switch over to the un-deprecated function:

1. Switch the function from `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:data error:&error]` to `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[Foo class] fromData:data error:&error]`, as the deprecation warning says.
2. Support **secure** coding:

   1. Switch your conformance from `NSCoding` to `NSSecureCoding` for your top-level object.
   2. Add the property:

      ```
      @property (class, readonly) BOOL supportsSecureCoding;
      ```
   3. Implement the method:

      ```
      + (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
          return YES;
      }
      ```
   4. If your object has any other properties that are `NSCoding` repeat all these steps for them so they end up conforming to `NSSecureCoding`.  For example, if there was a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) Bar *bar;` on your `Foo` object that is being encoded, you'd need to ensure that `Bar` also conforms to `NSSecureCoding` and not just `NSCoding`.
3. (Optional) Change your encoding call to require secure coding (i.e. the second parameter can be `YES`):

   ```
   [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];
   ```

It seems like Apple wants people to switch from `NSCoding` to `NSSecureCoding`, and the problem above would have been more obvious to resolve if `NSCoding` was deprecated too.

Comment: Had been searching for some time and this is the first comprehensible answer I've found. Thanks much, person!